# Product of single-occuring factors

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, products

I'm currently working on a project, where I need to store products of multiple integers. These integers are stored in a list. It should be possible to factor the product at a later point and retrieving the original factors. The product is relatively small, nothing that can't be factored by a computer by brute-force.

**Ideally the product should be as small as possible.**

So far the product $p$ is always in a from of:

$p = {f_1}^1 \times {f_2}^1 \times \ldots \times {f_n}^1$

All factors, unfortunately, need to be in the form of $f^1$, meaning no factors can occur multiple times.

I thought of using prime numbers as factors because I would obviously get the factors back by simply factoring the product.

I also noticed that I can use squares as a source of factors instead of only prime numbers. This way I can avoid creating a product that is too large, provided the square is smaller than one prime number.

So instead of using a set of only primes $S = \{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, \ldots\}$ I could also use squared numbers, i.e. $4$, since they would also just occur once as a factor in the prodcut: $S = \{2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 16, \ldots\}$.

---

As an example I would create a product $p = 2 \times 3 \times 7 \times 9 = 378$.

From just the number $378$ I could then clearly reconstruct the original factors again:

$378 = 2 \times 3^3 \times 7 = 2 \times 3 \times 7 \times 9$.

The problem I had without using prime numbers and squares was i.e. for the product $p = 12$:

Was $12$ created as $3 \times 4$ or $2 \times 6$?

---

My questions are:

- Do I need to use a list of prime numbers and squares or are there other numbers that can also fit in this list?
- Is there a different / better approach to achieve this?

Comment: what are you trying to do ? Make a factoring machine ? (I mean,  a machine that can factorise numbers)

Comment: @Spectre No, factoring is a part of the whole program, but not a new / special method, it factors the product via brute-force. As example: I send the product from A to B. A creates the product and B factors the product at a later point in time to retrieve the original factors. A & B then both know the original factors.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. BTW, the only easiest method I can give is prime factorising the product.

Comment: Unless your factors are prime numbers, the outcome will not be unique in some cases. For example, $84=6\times 14=4\times 21$. One of the factorizations contains no squares, and so is acceptable under your regime, but the other factorization does contain a square. Unless you have special rules to address such cases, your question can have no simple answer.